# WSO2IS IS source code version

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I see WO2 has migrates its source code to github that's great. My question is about the specific versions.

I've downloaded WSO2 IS 5.0.0 with SP1. Which version of the carbon-identity is in use here? For some features I'd like to debug, fix/complete and commit (however I see many  bugs/incompleteness has been already fixed in the milestone versions).

Have fun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

carbon-identity version is different from WSO2 IS version. You can refer product-is repository [1] and switch to required version branch and then refer the carbon-identity version which has been referred in the pom.xml.

[1] https://github.com/wso2/product-is/

Comment: Thank you .. I missed the 'product-is' repository.

Comment: Any hints to which branch could I commit fixes?

Comment: In your repository you can do fixes in any branch of your fork repository and do commits. If you want to contribute you can send a pull request to wso2 repository master branch from your fork. Better communicate with wso2 team with dev@wso2.org email group